# Search for matching keywords in word document based on a populated array of string from excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-word, string-matching

**What the program should do?**
I have two files; one Word file, and one Excel file. The Word file contains some text. The Excel file contains defined strings. What I'm trying to achieve is create a VBA program which will connect to an Excel file in the same or a different directory and get data from 2 columns of the Excel file and store them temporarily in a multi-dimensional array. The array will then be used to search for matching words within the document and highlight them.

**What I've achieved so far**
I have come up with the code to find matching words from the array in the word document and highlight them. What I'm still struggling with is the connection to the Excel file to get this array dynamically populated.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub HighlightMatches()
    Dim range As range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wordsArray

wordsArray = Array("Lion", "Hello", "Cat", "Lorem Ipsum")
For i = 0 To UBound(wordsArray)
    Set range = ActiveDocument.range

    With range.Find
    .Text = wordsArray(i)
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True
        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Loop
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

I would appreciate your ideas of how to achieve this in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Sub HighlightMultipleWords()

Dim sArr() As String
Dim rTmp As Range
Dim x As Long

sArr = Split("Cat Bat Rat") ' YOUR ARRAY OF WORDS
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

For x = 0 To UBound(sArr)
Set rTmp = ActiveDocument.Range

    With rTmp.Find
    .Text = sArr(x)
    .Replacement.Text = sArr(x)
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response  @ryguy72 but I think your VBA code belongs to excel but what I'm trying to do is create this program in VBA Word. Actually when I test your code from the Word VBEditor the "GetOpenFilename" method doesn't exist for Word so I think this won't do the job but I'm still looking for other ideas if you have. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now.  I updated my original post.  Try the code.  Does it do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your time @ryguy72 but the question is how can we populate the array of strings variable with strings present in an excel file. How to achieve that? That's where I'm getting stuck.